# Parallel Map Reduce Jobs in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have to run in hadoop 1.0.4 many (maybe 12) jobs. I want tha five first to run in parallel, and when all finish to run 4 other jobs in parallel and at last to run the last 3 again to run in parallel. How can i set it in hadoop 1.0.4 as i see that all jobs run one each other and not in parallel.

Comment: use oozie http://oozie.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

[JobControl](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) API can be used for MR job dependency. For complex work flows, [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) or [Azkaban](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban) is recommended. [Here](http://www.crobak.org/2012/07/workflow-engines-for-hadoop/) is Oozie vs Azkaban,

Comment: In my case can i user JobControl which seems to be easy to be used?

Comment: With JobControl API must i use the command job.waitForCompletion(true); after the end of each job or this is done automatically from JobControl?

Comment: I have message Job in state RUNNING instead of DEFINE

Comment: How did you solve the problem of "Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING" in oozie.